# Image falling out of bootstrap card after adding custom CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I have added custom CSS to flip the image n show text in a bootstrap site, but the image falls out of bootstrap card.
One solution I found was to add image height, but that makes its irresponsive.
I want the image in the card + want it to be responsive.
It's a temporary portfolio site I am trying to develop to learn bootstrap.
[problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhSzb.png)

````
.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 400px; */
}
```
```
<div class="card-body text-center">
    <h3 class="card-title mb-3">GCET Prep App</h3>
    <div class="flip-container">
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
          <img src="1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="#" />
        </div>
        <div class="back">
          <p class="card-text">
            text
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="card-text">
      (Deployed on playstore)
      <br />
      An app for Gcet Preparation
    </p>
    <a
      href=""
      target="_blank"
      class="btn btn-danger me-5"
      >Playstore</a>
  </div>
````

[Zip file of full project drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yfBBbTAhAr7zG0vdAcizooKDSLs1E6bw/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by taking the front (image) as relative (position) n back (text) as absolute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by taking the front (image) as relative (position) n back (text) as absolute.

Answer (score 1):

add `style="height: 100%;"` to .card class

Comment: .card is actually a bootstrap card. We can override it?

Comment: you can add 'h-100'  class or can create a custom class for that

Comment: Tried didn't work. I may be doing something wrong, can u plz show a sample code! Also thx for looking into the issue!

Comment: Hey! I was able to fix the issue by taking the front (image) as relative (position) n back (text) as absolute. Will that cause me any issue in devices of different sizes?